# Way to submit a "hidden" form through link and button clicks with Vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I am still pretty new to Vue.js 3 and am wondering if there is a way to do what I'm attempting utilizing Vue.js (but I am open to plain JavaScript if not).

I am wishing to submit a form containing hidden fields on a page when any of the link/button items are clicked: the  tag containing "Click here", the placeholder image, and the actual button itself.

The fields I'm wishing to submit are contained in the "VISIT specific hidden inputs here" comment.
Additionally, I am wanting an outside link to open when any of those three are clicked. So on submit it will submit the hidden form AND open the link.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <style></style>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.11"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@next"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="d-flex flex-column h-100" id="awApp">
    <header>
      <!-- FIXED NAVBAR AND/OR HEADER -->
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand">
            <img :src="imgSrc" alt="logo" width="200" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- / HEADER/NAVBAR -->

    <!-- TOP CONTENT -->
    <main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0 aw-index">
      <div class="container pt-0">
        <div class="row gx-5">
          <div class="col-md-7 text-light my-auto"></div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="card shadow aw-index p-3">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title aw-orange aw-font-droid">
                  Download Your Book
                </h4>
                <form>
                  <!-- VISIT specific hidden inputs here -->
                  <input type="hidden" name="z_submit_date" v-model="now" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="z_utm_source" value="Source" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="z_utm_medium" value="Medium" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="z_utm_campaign" value="Campaign" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="z_utm_content" value="Content" />
                  <!-- /VISIT specific hidden inputs here -->
                  <h5 class="card-text aw-orange aw-font-freight-light">
                    <a class="aw-orange" href="" target="_blank">Click here</a>
                    to download it now.
                  </h5>
                  <div class="row text-center">
                    <a href="" target="_blank">
                      <img
                        class="img-fluid"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200"
                      />
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row text-center mt-4">
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      class="
                        btn
                        aw-bg-orange
                        text-dark
                        aw-font-freight-semibold-regular aw-background-orange
                      "
                      value="Submit"
                    >
                      <strong>Download</strong>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <!-- /TOP CONTENT -->

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-secondary"></footer>
    <!-- /FOOTER -->
  </body>

  <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <!-- /BOOTSTRAP JS -->

  <!-- VUE APP CODE -->
  <script>
    const app = Vue.createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
          now: new Date().toISOString(),
        };
      },
      methods: {
        submitForm(e) {},
      },
    });

    app.mount("#awApp");
  </script>
  <!-- /VUE APP CODE-->
</html>
```

Comment: Just attach the `v-on:click` event listeners to the element you want to listen click events to, and then call the method that submits the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `click`-handlers to the links and buttons that calls `submitForm`, and update `submitForm` to also open the download URL:

1. Add a [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html) to the `<form>` so that we can use it later to create the `FormData` to submit, including the hidden form fields:

   ```html
   <form ref="form">
   ```
2. Add a `click`-handler to the links and buttons with the [`.prevent` modifier](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#event-modifiers) to prevent the default action, since we'll programatically open the download URL:

   ```html
   <a class="aw-orange" :href="downloadUrl" @click.prevent="submitForm" target="_blank">Click here</a>
   <a :href="downloadUrl" @click.prevent="submitForm" target="_blank">
      <img
            class="img-fluid"
            src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200"
      />
   </a>
   <button @click.prevent="submitForm">
     <strong>Download</strong>
   </button>
   ```
3. Update `submitForm()` to create a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) from the `<form>` template ref, submit the form with [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), and [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) the download URL:

   ```js
   export default {
     methods: {
       submitForm() {
         const formData = new FormData(this.$refs.form)
         fetch(this.submitUrl, { method: 'POST', body: formData })
           .then(resp => resp.json())
           .then(json => this.response = json)

         window.open(this.downloadUrl, '_blank')
       }
     }
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OJpePJN?editors=1000)